# remove illegal characters from file name javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I've seen the various posts regarding this topic, but I'm getting a strange result when I do the following:

```
var dirtyString = '<>I\really|\re\ad?"the/wh\ole*:da|\y?.'
var cleanString = dirtyString.replace(/[\/:*?"<>|.]/g, "");
console.log(cleanString);
```

It removes all the illegal characters, but the "r" letters are also removed.  In the console log I'm getting "Ieallyeadthewholeday"  It seems that "\" before "r" erases the "r".  "\" isn't erasing other letters it comes before.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\r` is the Carriage Return character. If you want a backslash followed by an `r` then you need to escape the backslash: `\\r`.

`\y` is not a reserved escape sequence, so JavaScript interprets it as `\` followed by `y`. Other programming languages, like C#, will instead raise a compiler error about an unrecognised escape sequence.

Further confounding things: most regular-expression syntaxes have their own backslash escape sequences that are distinct from the hosting language's, such as the character-classes `\W`, `\d` etc. Fortunately they work because `\W` and `\d` are not reserved in JavaScript, but in this author's opinion it makes sense to escape the backslashes then just to make things really clear to the reader, or if you're wanting to make your regexes portable between languages.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm kind of stuck though.  Basically, my user can enter a string into a text box and that string will be used as a file name.  I wanted to remove all illegal characters before making it the file name.  So if the user happens to type in \r in their string, then I just have to accept that the r will be erased?

Comment: @user3080392 don't rely on client-side validation. If a user disables JavaScript and uploads an invalid filename then what happens?

Comment: Yeah, maybe I'll figure out a different way of naming the file.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you would try `console.log(dirtyString)` you would also see that your "r" are "missing" too.

This is because '\r' is actually an escape sequence for *Carriage Return* character (code 13). Your replace() does nothing to it. It is still there just isn't displayed. Try playing with `String.charAt()` and `String.charCodeAt()` and you will see that the character is still there.

As a side note you are trying to remove "blacklisted" characters and blacklisting is almost never right approach. As you can see in your own case you forgot to blacklist '\r' character (and many others). Much safer is whitelisting. For example you may decide that you accept only latin letters and digits, then remove everything not whitelisted: `var cleanString = dirtyString.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/gi, "");`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on whitelisting.  I didn't know about that.  I wonder, which part of (/[^a-z0-9]/gi, ""); is saying "except for" or "not" a-z0-9.  Is it the ^ symbol?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, its the ^ symbol. For more info on regular expressions check http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html